# NServiceBus: Events, Multiple Inheritance, Handlers being called more than once per event

Tags: nservicebus

I'm have some mysterious problems with handlers being called more than once per event which appears to be correlated with events built up via interface inheritance.

We are using only interfaces for our messages and using`NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection.MessageMapper().CreateInstance()` to create instances to put on the bus.

Our interfaces:

`IOperationOccured` - Contains basic operation information, subscribers to this event act on things in a fairly generic way. This event is never raised directly.

`ISpecificOperationOccured` - Inherits `IOperationOccured`. Contains more specific information. Subscribers to this event are able to do more specific things since the event is more specific.

The problem is that when `ISpecificOperationOccured` is raised, the handlers for `IOperationOccured` are called, the handlers for `ISpecificOperationOccured` are called and then the message appears to get processed again, calling the handlers again.

What am I misunderstanding? I'd expect the handlers for `IOperationOccured` to get called once per event and the handlers for `ISpecificOperationOccured` to get called **once** per event.

Comment: You can just do Bus.CreateInstance<T>() instead to instantiate the interface.

Comment: I could not repro this in my test solution with a similar hierarchy, can you show us how your handlers are setup and also the concrete message implementations?

Comment: @Udi Dahan: Will that have a substantive difference over using the MessageMapper? We have actually wrapped the MessageMapper with some validation code...

Comment: @foosnazzy: There are not concrete message implementations. The handlers are straightforward implementations of `IHandleMessages<>`.

Make sure that `IOperationOccured` inherits `IMessage`, not `ISpecificOperationOccured`

Comment: So are they being proxied?  I'm just wondering if that is the part that may be throwing us off.  Showing the code to put messages on the bus would help along with a sample handler signature.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer I know but hopefully this will help others.

This happens when your separate handlers for IOperationOccured and ISpecificOperationOccured are deployed in the same endpoint. e.g.

- Endpoint1 (Raises ISpecificOperationOccured)
- Endpoint2 (Handles both IOperationOccured and ISpecificOperationOccured)

Endpoint1.Subscriptions will contain entries for:

- IOperationOccured -> Endpoint2
- ISpecificOperationOccured -> Endpoint2

So that when ISpecificOperationOccured is published it will get sent to Endpoint2 twice. The recommended approach is to have separate endpoints for the handling of different message types. e.g.

- Endpoint1 (Raises ISpecificOperationOccured)
- Endpoint2 (Handles IOperationOccured)
- Endpoint3 (Handles ISpecificOperationOccured)

Comment: Can you give references for the recommended approach?

Comment: The documentation for this approach is sparse but you can find some guidance here: http://www.nservicebus.com/Monitoring.aspx, http://www.nservicebus.com/Sagas.aspx

Comment: This workaround is extremely annoying. To me, this seems like a bug. If moving the handles to two endpoints changes the number of times the messages are processed, then the design is wrong.